# Análise de cluster por grupos

Tags: r

Estou a tentar uma análise de *cluster* para vários grupos dentro de um dataframe, ***com o objetivo de retornar as características desta análise*** (ex. os grupos resultantes da mesma) em um banco de dados através da função `tidy` (`broom`).

`dput`

```
dataset=structure(list(a = c(28L, 19L, 92L, 35L, 42L, 82L, 91L, 98L, 
58L, 58L, 92L, 61L, 67L, 73L, 4L, 35L, 9L, 17L, 7L, 82L, 24L,   
51L, 45L, 1L, 97L, 97L, 99L, 5L, 67L, 97L, 95L, 77L, 56L, 67L, 
80L, 22L, 87L, 31L, 97L, 15L, 12L, 94L, 18L, 86L, 1L, 99L, 2L, 
88L, 84L, 65L, 59L, 38L, 8L, 46L, 66L, 30L, 32L, 36L, 17L, 35L, 
40L, 16L, 60L, 28L, 47L, 56L, 82L, 88L, 76L, 38L, 88L, 61L, 26L, 
64L, 24L, 48L, 30L, 68L, 88L, 42L, 62L, 12L, 76L, 37L, 25L, 91L, 
18L, 76L, 13L, 24L, 49L, 89L, 35L, 88L, 19L, 24L, 62L, 91L, 99L,  
18L), b = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("group1", 
"group2", "group3", "group4"), class = "factor"), c = c(61L, 
28L, 82L, 38L, 22L, 79L, 7L, 12L, 73L, 78L, 17L, 28L, 30L, 11L, 
99L, 47L, 42L, 51L, 13L, 16L, 35L, 51L, 92L, 41L, 45L, 27L, 17L, 
37L, 27L, 53L, 23L, 50L, 81L, 25L, 93L, 11L, 80L, 35L, 32L, 9L, 
56L, 18L, 17L, 63L, 49L, 11L, 26L, 93L, 45L, 7L, 43L, 90L, 31L, 
80L, 53L, 66L, 62L, 13L, 54L, 7L, 20L, 37L, 79L, 52L, 35L, 8L, 
6L, 46L, 35L, 3L, 18L, 82L, 92L, 80L, 8L, 87L, 89L, 20L, 26L, 
86L, 29L, 55L, 46L, 83L, 66L, 25L, 17L, 68L, 21L, 83L, 26L, 97L, 
54L, 71L, 19L, 6L, 20L, 86L, 83L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

Tentei isso:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

res1<-dataset%>%
group_by(b)%>%
do(cluster= 
       kmeans(dataset[,c(1,3)],centers=3))

res2<-tidy(res1,cluster)
```

Mas não consigo o que quero (o dataframe resultante deveria ter 100 linhas, cada uma com o seu respectivo grupo, derivado da análise). Existe um erro no meu código, ***ou***, esta função não é adequada para executar esta ação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta função não é adequada para esta ação, pelo menos não do jeito que está sendo usada aqui. O truque é usar a função `nest` do pacote `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr
cluster <- dataset %>%
  nest(a, c) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, kmeans, 3),
         centers = map(model, tidy))
```

Com ela, eu consigo dizer como o `R` deve agrupar em uma lista (neste caso, uma lista com `levels(dataset$b)` elementos) as colunas que me interessam para fazer a minha clusterização. Depois uso `mutate` para, de fato, encontrar a clusterização destes dados.

Veja que o resultado é condizente com o esperado:

```
cluster %>%
  unnest(centers)

        b       x1       x2 size withinss cluster
1  group1 82.62500 20.75000    8 2529.375       1
2  group1 56.50000 83.83333    6 5278.333       2
3  group1 24.36364 39.00000   11 4378.545       3
4  group2 86.40000 23.20000   10 2952.000       1
5  group2 13.25000 30.00000    8 2861.500       2
6  group2 81.57143 73.28571    7 2947.143       3
7  group3 40.20000 73.70000   10 4321.700       1
8  group3 76.50000 33.50000    6 2337.000       2
9  group3 33.33333 18.00000    9 3200.000       3
10 group4 87.25000 62.75000    8 5699.000       1
11 group4 31.62500 75.37500    8 2415.750       2
12 group4 37.00000 18.44444    9 4592.222       3
```

O problema é que ainda não temos o que realmente te interessa, que é o cluster ao qual pertence cada observação. Mas nós temos os centros de cada cluster. Assim, podemos prever, através da distância euclidiana, qual é o cluster de cada observação. Para isso, usaremos a função `cl_predict` do pacote `clue`:

```
dataset %>%
  filter(b=="group1") %>%
  select(-b) %>%
  cl_predict(cluster$model[[1]], .)

Class ids:
 [1] 3 3 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 2 3 1
```

Eu não consegui fazer esta predição para todos os modelos ao mesmo tempo. Para obter todas as 100 predições necessárias, teria que, de alguma maneira, fazer o `cluster$model[[1]]` variar, seja de alguma maneira tidy, seja usando um `for`.

Outra coisa que também não sei como fazer é clusterizar os dados com números de clusters diferentes por grupo. Foram procurados 3 clusters em todos os 4 grupos da variável `b`. Não sei se isto seria algo razoável de ser fazer na prática.

Mas estas duas tarefas deixarei a cargo do leitor : )